# docx4j cannot read POI saved files, who is at fault?

Tags: ms-office, apache-poi, docx4j

When I save a docx file after processing some text with XPath using POI, I then pass the ByteArrayOutputStream to a new ByteArrayInputStream and feed it to dox4j with

```
wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(
    bis
);
```

With 3 out of 4 of my templates this throws an exception:

```
  org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.InvalidFormatException: Unexpected package (docx4j supports docx/docxm and pptx only
     at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.createPackage(ContentTypeManager.java:834)
```

The code looks something like this:

```
    /* Return a package of the appropriate type.  Used when loading an existing
 * Package, with an already populated [Content_Types].xml.  When 
 * creating a new Package, start with the new WordprocessingMLPackage constructor. */
public OpcPackage createPackage() throws InvalidFormatException { 

    /*
     * How do we know what type of Package this is?
     * 
     * In principle, either:
     * 
     * 1. We were told its file extension or mime type in the
     * constructor/method parameters, or
     * 
     * 2. Because [Content_Types].xml contains an override for PartName
     * /document.xml of content type
     * application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml
     * 
     * The latter approach is more reliable, so ..
     * 
     */
    OpcPackage p;

    if (getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT) != null
            || getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.WORDPROCESSINGML_DOCUMENT_MACROENABLED) != null
            || getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.WORDPROCESSINGML_TEMPLATE ) != null
            || getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.WORDPROCESSINGML_TEMPLATE_MACROENABLED) != null ) { 
        log.info("Detected WordProcessingML package ");
        p = new WordprocessingMLPackage(this);
        return p;
    } else if (getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.PRESENTATIONML_MAIN) != null
            || getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.PRESENTATIONML_TEMPLATE) != null
            || getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.PRESENTATIONML_SLIDESHOW) != null) { 
        log.info("Detected PresentationMLPackage package ");
        p = new PresentationMLPackage(this);
        return p;
    } else if (getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.SPREADSHEETML_WORKBOOK) != null
            || getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.SPREADSHEETML_WORKBOOK_MACROENABLED) != null
            || getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.SPREADSHEETML_TEMPLATE) != null
            || getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.SPREADSHEETML_TEMPLATE_MACROENABLED) != null) {
        //  "xlam", "xlsb" ?
        log.info("Detected SpreadhseetMLPackage package ");
        p = new SpreadsheetMLPackage(this);
        return p;

    } else if (getPartNameOverridenByContentType(ContentTypes.DRAWINGML_DIAGRAM_LAYOUT) != null) {
        log.info("Detected Glox file ");
        p = new GloxPackage(this);
        return p;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidFormatException("Unexpected package (docx4j supports docx/docxm and pptx only");
        //return new Package(this);
    }
}
```

It seems to be failing to match some specific content type override.  In my starting docx templates there is a [Content_Types].xml file which has:

```
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Override PartName="/_rels/.rels"       ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/word/fontTable.xml"        ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels"      ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/word/media/image1.wmf"         ContentType="image/x-wmf" />
    <Override PartName="/word/comments.xml"         ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml"        ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/word/footer1.xml"      ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footer+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/word/document.xml"         ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/word/styles.xml"       ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml"      ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml" />
    <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml"         ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml" />
</Types>
```

After processing with POI the [Content_Types].xml looks like this:

```
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
  <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/_rels/.rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/docProps/app.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.extended-properties+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/docProps/core.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.core-properties+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/comments.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.comments+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/fontTable.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/footer1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.footer+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/media/image1.wmf" ContentType="image/x-wmf"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/numbering.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.numbering+xml"/>
  <Override PartName="/word/styles.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml"/>
</Types>
```

Notice that the Override for PartName="/word/document.xml" is missing!

Is this an acceptable file content types file without the word/document.xml override?  It opens in LibreOffice without complaints.  Is docx4j relying on Override tags which may not be present in the content types, or is POI not correctly writing content types for some of my files (3 out of 4).

Comment: I think it's a docx4j bug - POI is setting a default with the right type that docx4j looks to be ignoring.

Comment: I agree, I have opened issue 46 on the github project with some code ideas to fix it.  I'm still wondering what the spec says with regards to Override tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclosure: I'm docx4j project lead**

What POI is doing seems to be legal per the specification, but isn't ideal.

Per ECMA-376 Part 2, "Getting the Content Type of a Part", docx4j should find the content type of the docx when specified the way POI does it.

The WordprocessingML chapter in Part 1, says in the "Package Structure" section:

> First, the content type for relationship parts and the Main Document
>   part (the only required part) must be defined (physically located at
>   /[Content_Types].xml in the package):

```
<Types
 xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
 &lt;Default Extension="rels"
 ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformatspackage.
 relationships+xml"/> 
<Override PartName="/document.xml"
 ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.
 wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"/> </Types>
```

My reading of that is that you must define the content type of the Main Document part (which POI does), and the hint only is to use an Override to do so.

It doesn't make much sense to me to use up your .xml default for something that will match one (or perhaps 2 or 3 parts) when most of the parts are .xml and will require an override to specify something different.  I wonder why POI did it this way - different to the suggestion in the spec, and different to what Word emits.

That said, https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/commit/1c1190fc3a2fc6e191c825a0e30fde2654cc997c should fix this.